# How to get a single paragraph from the Wikipedia API

Tags: javascript, wikipedia-api

How can I generate a URL request like this?

```
var CityURL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=boston&format=json&formatversion=2&exintro=1&callback=?';
```

to `Group C` of a wiki like this in API

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_AFC_Champions_League_group_stage#Group_C
```

I already tried this

```
    var games= 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=2018_AFC_Champions_League_group_stage#Group_C&format=json&formatversion=2&exintro=1&callback=?';
```

but not getting anything.

This is returning the first paragraph of page

```
    var games= 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=2018_AFC_Champions_League_group_stage&format=json&formatversion=2&exintro=1&callback=?';
```

but as I said I just need the `#Group_C` and the complete URL not returning anything.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var games= 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=2018_AFC_Champions_League_group_stage#Group_C&format=json&formatversion=2&exintro=1&callback=?';

        $.getJSON(games,function(data) {
            $.each(data.query.pages, function(i, item) {
                       $('div#details2').html(item.extract);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? What do the dos say about this if anything? can you add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
?

Comment: Ok I updated the post and as you can see I follows exact structure as the `CityURL` but nothing back in result

Comment: You are assigning a string to a variable, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve]

Comment: Hi Amy I have put every thing in the post

Comment: No you haven't.  Assigning a string to a variable doesn't fetch data from a server.  I will remove my downvote once the question contains a [mcve].

Comment: Why r u guys are down voting this question , For God sake?!

Comment: We told you why.  I removed my downvote now that your question is more complete.  We can't read your mind to see how you're performing the request.  For all we know, its *how* you perform the request that is the issue.  That's why we request a [mcve].

Comment: @Amy I have now everything on post as you can see it is a simple Ajax request

Comment: I don't know if the api allows for getting a paragraph but the `#Group_C` part will only cut off parameters sent to the server, everything after `#` is used by browsers and called a hash. It causes a browser to scroll to an element with `#id` or a header with `#headertext` but you can't use `#` in json API's. I've updated the title to be more descriptive of what you need.

Comment: I suggest you read [the API documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page). It tells you all of the possible parameters you can use and what they return.

Comment: Making a get request to the [api root url](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) will get you some detailed documentation as well but searching for the word `paragraph` got me nothing so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `action=parse` to get the HTML of a specific section.

First you have to find out the sectionindex by calling:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=sections&page=2018_AFC_Champions_League_group_stage&format=json&formatversion=2&callback=?
```

In this case the index for "Group_C" is 8.

The following URL returns the text for your desired section. Just replace parameter `section` with the index number obtained by the previous request.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=text&page=2018_AFC_Champions_League_group_stage&section=8&format=json&formatversion=2&callback=?
```

Comment: Thanks a lots Eric , I am able to access to the URL through browse now but should I have to update the  `$.getJSON()` as well? because I am not getting any thing now

Comment: I forgot to add `&callback=?` to the URL so that it will use JSONP instead of JSON. And you have to update `$.getJSON()` because the returned JSON has a different structure.
`$.getJSON(games,function(data) {
           $('div#details2').html(data.parse.text);
        });`